# Functionally idiomatic FFT

Tags: functional-programming, f#, fft

I've written the this radix-2 FFT with the goal of making it functionally idiomatic without sacrificing too much performance:

```
let reverse x bits =
    let rec reverse' x bits y =
        match bits with
        | 0 -> y
        | _ -> ((y <<< 1) ||| (x &&& 1))
               |> reverse' (x >>> 1) (bits - 1) 
     reverse' x bits 0 

let radix2 (vector: Complex[]) (direction: int) =
    let z = vector.Length
    let depth = floor(Math.Log(double z, 2.0)) |> int
    if (1 <<< depth) <> z then failwith "Vector length is not a power of 2"

    // Complex roots of unity; "twiddle factors"
    let unity: Complex[] =
        let xpn = float direction * Math.PI / double z
        Array.Parallel.init<Complex> (z/2) (fun i ->
            Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(1.0, (float i) * xpn))

    // Permutes elements of input vector via bit-reversal permutation
    let pvec = Array.Parallel.init z (fun i -> vector.[reverse i depth])

    let outerLoop (vec: Complex[]) =
        let rec recLoop size =
            if size <= z then
                let mid, step = size / 2, z / size
                let rec inrecLoop i =
                    if i < z then
                        let rec bottomLoop idx k =
                            if idx < i + mid then
                                let temp = vec.[idx + mid] * unity.[k]
                                vec.[idx + mid] <- (vec.[idx] - temp)
                                vec.[idx] <- (vec.[idx] + temp)
                                bottomLoop (idx + 1) (k + step)
                        bottomLoop i 0
                        inrecLoop (i + size)
                inrecLoop 0
                recLoop (size * 2)
        recLoop 2
        vec

    outerLoop pvec
```

The `outerLoop` segment is the biggest nested tail-recursive mess I have ever written. I replicated the algorithm in the Wikipedia article for the [Cooley-Tukey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm), but the only functional constructs I could think to implement using higher-order functions result in massive hits to both performance and memory efficiency. Are there other solutions that would yield the same results without resulting in massive slow-downs, while still being idiomatic?

Comment: I have no knowledge of F# and I'm asking this only out of curiosity: is this _idiomatic_ F#?

Comment: Is the indentation correct? From looking at the code I have a feeling your ``bottomLoop`` is never called…

Comment: @dumetrulo should be fixed now. Probably got mangled in the copy.

Comment: @chb my understanding is that functional languages prefer immutability and higher-order functions. So no, hence my asking what a more idiomatic solution might look like.

Comment: @mribrainguy Have a look at this question on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196112/in-functional-programming-are-local-mutable-variables-with-no-side-effects-stil). It touches upon tail recursion, local, mutable variables, and the notion of a _pure function_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on how the algorithm works, so there might be a nice functional implementation, but it is worth noting that using a localised mutation is perfectly idiomatic in F#.

Your `radix2` function is functional from the outside - it takes `vector` array as an input, never mutates it, creates a new array `pvec` which it then initializes (using some mutation along the way) and then returns it. This is a similar pattern to what built-in functions like `Array.map` use (which initializes a new array, mutates it and then returns it). This is often a sensible way of doing things, because some algorithms are better written using mutation.

In this case, it's perfectly reasonable to also use local mutable variables and loops. Doing that will make your code more readable compared to the tail-recursive version. I have not tested this, but my naive translation of your `outerLoop` function would just be to use three nested loops - something like this:

```
let mutable size = 2
while size <= z do
    let mid, step = size / 2, z / size
    let mutable i = 0
    while i < z do
        for j in 0 .. mid - 1 do
            let idx, k = i + j, step * j
            let temp = pvec.[idx + mid] * unity.[k]
            pvec.[idx + mid] <- (pvec.[idx] - temp)
            pvec.[idx] <- (pvec.[idx] + temp)
        i <- i + size
    size <- size * 2
```

This might not be exactly right (I did this just be refactoring your code), but I think it's actually more idiomatic than using complex nested tail-recursive functions in this case.

Comment: I think this is the answer I didn't know I needed. I had been assuming that mutation was a code smell that should be avoided where possible, but local mutation definitely seems like a reasonable compromise and is probably going to help me with performance critical parts of my code.

Comment: You may have seen this [F# FFT](http://www.fssnip.net/dC/title/fast-Fourier-transforms-FFT-) but the performance is horrible. I wondered if there was a way to achieve something similar without the performance issues but with your advice I think I have a good direction in which to proceed.